# Kotlin how to declare chained fields with same data type

Tags: kotlin

In other programming languages like Java if you want to chain fields, you do like: `String a, b, c, d;`

Is it possible to chain fields in Kotlin too, like `val a, b, c, d`?
[here doesn`t provide any info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

Answer (score 6):

No, `Kotlin` does not support declaration of multiple variable in a statement.

`Kotlin` has learned some good lessons from Java. One of that is variable declaration. Though Java support multiple variable declaration in a line, Oracle's Java Guidelines says use only one declaration per line.

> Following is mentioned in Oracle Java Standard:

One declaration per line is recommended since it encourages commenting. In other words,

```
int level; // indentation level
int size; // size of table
```

is preferred over

```
int level, size;
```

In absolutely no case should variables and functions be declared on the same line. Example:

```
long dbaddr, getDbaddr(); // WRONG!
```

Do not put different types on the same line. Example:

```
int foo, fooarray[]; //WRONG!
```

Note: The examples above use one space between the type and the identifier. Another

```
acceptable alternative is to use tabs, e.g.:

int level; // indentation level
int size; // size of table
Object currentEntry; // currently selected table entry
```

Refer this link for Oracle convention: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf. Page no. 14 > Declarations.

There has been some huge debates on this topic of `type of declaration should be used for Java`. So `Kotlin` just removed that as an option.

Comment: Did you quote this? Can you provide the link if so. Would be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

First, Kotlin is a [null-safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) language which means you can't declare fields without initializing them, and Kotlin has no **default value** for any types even if it is **nullable**, but there is an exception for the primitive array, e.g:`IntArray(size)` the default value likes as java are `0`. So you can't write the form of the field declaration as in Java, for example:

```
//Java
private String a,b,c;// they are `null` by default.

private val a:String? // error: property must be initialized
```

Secondly, If you are concerned about the definition of fields/variables, they are totally different. the field/variable type is declared at the **right-side**, which means you can't declare a **unified** fields/variables in Kotlin at all, so it doesn't make sense in Kotlin, for example:

```
//Java
String a,b;

//Kotlin
val a,  b;
//  ^---^--- how to declare the variables type?

//            v-- just more than one `val` after introduce the variable types
val a:String; val b:String;
```

Finally, field is a **heavy component** in Kotlin. when you declare a field in Java it is merely a field, no more. but in Kotlin when you declare a field, it maybe a property/field. and a property has getter/backing field(?)/setter(?), for example:

```
// java
String a; //just a field

// kotlin
var a:String = "a" // has a backing field, getter & setter

private var b:String = "b" // it is just a field

@JvmField var c:String = "c" 
//            ^--- it is a field but it has getter/setter in reflect  
//                 e.g: this::c.getter & this::c.setter
```